# Как создать общий List<> для всех форм?(WinForms, C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, list

У меня есть две формы, одна добавляет в лист данные, вторая считывает, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь кнопкой [править](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/653096/edit) и добавте ваш код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как-то так

```
static class InnerData
{
  static public List<Data> AllData = new List<Data>();
}
```

добавление

```
InnerData.AllData.Add(data);
```

чтение

```
foreach(Data data in InnerData.AllData)
{
  //something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, Вам нужно создать некий объект, функцией которого будет хранить данные, которыми могут пользоваться другие объекты Вашего приложения. Следовательно Вам нужен объект, экземпляр которого будет единым для всего приложения, и будет создан единожды. А если ожидается работа из нескольких потоков с полями, свойствами и методами этого класса, то этот класс должен ещё и обеспечивать потокобезопасность.
Для решения этой задачи отлично подходит такой паттерн, как [Singleton (Одиночка)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class MyDataClass { public String MyProperty { get; set; } }


    public sealed class ConcurrentDataSingleton
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Объект для обеспечения потокобезопасного доступа к полям одиночки
        /// </summary>
        private readonly static object _lockObject = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// Коллекция данных
        /// </summary>
        private List<MyDataClass> _data;

        /// <summary>
        /// Статическое поле, хранящее ссылку на объект одиночки в управляемой куче
        /// </summary>
        private static ConcurrentDataSingleton instance;

        /// <summary>
        /// Метод получения ссылки на объект-одиночку
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static ConcurrentDataSingleton GetInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new ConcurrentDataSingleton();
            return instance;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Закрытый конструктор, инициализирующий поля класса
        /// </summary>
        private ConcurrentDataSingleton()
        {
            this._data = new List<MyDataClass>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Метод добавления объекта в коллекцию (потокобезопасно)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">Объект данных</param>
        public void AddData(MyDataClass data)
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                this._data.Add(data);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Метод получения данных (потокобезопасно)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="predicate">Условие, по которому следует выбирать объекты из коллекции</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<MyDataClass> GetData(Expression<Func<MyDataClass, Boolean>> predicate)
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                return this._data.AsQueryable().Where(predicate).ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            //получаем ссылку на хранилище данных
            ConcurrentDataSingleton dataStore = ConcurrentDataSingleton.GetInstance();

            //Добавление данных
            dataStore.AddData(new MyDataClass() { MyProperty = "value" });

            //Получение данных
            List<MyDataClass> dataThatINeed = dataStore.GetData(mdc => mdc.MyProperty == "value");
        }
    }
}
```